# How to calculate average count in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Question: Let’s say you have a business table and a policies table. If you wanted to calculate average policies per business in each city, what join type would you use and why?

FAQs:
What columns are in each table?
Business: business_id, city
Policies: business_id, policy_id

There are businesses with no policy which we will include in the average.
There is only one row for each business in the business table.

I tried:

```
SELECT Business_id, AVG(policy_id) 
FROM Policies 
JOIN Business 
ON business_id = business_id
```

Comment: If you want businesses without policies to be included in the average, then you'll want to use a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`, depending on how you write the query. If you post what you've tried so far, someone might help you fix your query.

Comment: @fubar I'm struggling to write it and would appreciate any help to do it

Comment: @barmar apologies i tried this so far SELECT Business_id, AVG(policy_id)
FROM Policies
JOIN Business ON business_id = business_id

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting a count of policies, you're averaging the IDs, which is a meaningless number.

Also, you're missing `GROUP BY`.

You need to write a subquery that gets the number of policies per business and city. Then the main query can average the number per city.

And when you have the same column in multiple tables, you need to refer to them with a table prefix to disambiguate.

```
SELECT city, AVG(policy_count) 
FROM (
    SELECT city, b.business, COUNT(p.policy_id) AS policy_count
    FROM business AS b
    LEFT JOIN policies AS p ON b.business_id = p.business_id
    GROUP BY city, b.business
) AS x
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use aggregation -- count the number of policies and divide by the number of businesses:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.business_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT Business_id)
FROM Business b LEFT JOIN
     Policies p
     ON b.business_id = p.business_id ;
```

Another way to write this:

```
select count(*) / (select count(*) from business)
from policies p;
```